# 51Degrees.mobi Logging Slows Down ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-4, 51degrees

The following line in `51Degrees.mobi.config` adds 2-3 seconds of loading time to each of my ASP.NET MVC 4 project's controller actions:

```
<fiftyOne>
    <log logFile="~/bin/App_Data/51Log.txt" logLevel="Info" />
    ...
</fiftyOne
```

The same thing happens for ASP.NET MVC 3. If I remove the `<log>` section, pages load almost instantly. I'm using the binary device database for detection like so:

```
<detection binaryFilePath="~/App_Data/51Degrees.mobi-Lite-2012.01.05.dat" />
```

Setting the `logLevel` to `Debug` causes the following exception:

```
`Storage scopes cannot be created when _AppStart is executing.`
```

Why does this cause such a drastic slowdown? Is it a symptom of a deeper problem?

Could there be an incompatibility with StructureMap for dependency injection?

---

**Update:** Thanks to @James Rosewell, I figured out why the logging slowed down my application. It's related to the *`logFile` path*. Everytime 51Degrees writes to the 51Log.txt file in the `~/bin` directory, it causes IIS to recycle the pool and reload all the modules. Changing the log path to `~/App_Data` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have responded to this thread on the 51Degrees.mobi forum. Please go to this link.

http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Forum/tabid/65/forumid/2/threadid/1519/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Thanks,

James

Comment: Thanks, solved it. Added update. If you post the solution on my other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7860241/198927, I'd be happy to award you the bounty :).

Comment: copy and paste of OP's question to your forums and only responding there is lame.